# Cannot connect to POS printer over TCP 9100

Tags: c#, printing, escpos

I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2012 Express, C#, .NET Framework **2.0**
- POS printer : **TYSSO PRP-300**, IP:192.168.1.100

I connect successfully to the printer using:

```
C:\> telnet 192.168.1.100 9100
_
```

Also using:

```
C:\> portqry -n 192.168.1.100 -e 9100 -p TCP
TCP port 9100 (unknown service): LISTENING
```

But when using this code:

```
TcpClient c = new TcpClient("192.168.1.100", 9100);
```

I got this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0):

It works when I compile the same code with **.NET framework 4.0**

I think there was a problem with **2.0 version**!